# Centered shear/skew in postscript

Tags: postscript, skew

I'm trying to apply skewing to an image in postscript. I have successfully done it with:

```
[1 -0.5 -0.5 1 0 0] concat
```

Where both `-0.5` refers to a skew of 22.5 degrees on the vertical and horizontal axis. The problem is that the skewing is not centered, the center of the image is moved so my image doesn't stay on the same position after applying the skew.

How can I apply skewing while maintaining the position? I tried translating the image before/after skewing but I can't find how much I should translate the image so it always stays in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally find the way to do it. First of all, position the element as usual with translate:

```
1135 568 translate
```

Then, skew the only on one axis X or Y, not both at the same time. The number in the matrix is `tan(skew_angle)` so for example, for a 20 degree angle on the X axis:

```
[1 0 0.3639 1 0 0] concat
```

After this, translate the image because now the width of the bounding box of the image is bigger, we can calculate this additional width as `additional_width = abs(object_height * tan(skew_angle))`. So now we translate half this width:

```
{additional_width/2} 0 translate
```

Now we do the skew on Y on the same way:

```
[1 0.3639 0 1 0 0] concat
```

And calculate the additional height as `additional_height = abs(object_width * tan(skew_angle))`

```
0 {additional_height/2} translate
```

On this way, after applying the skew the object center stays in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Skewing works by altering the current transformation matrix, it isn't centered at all.

Image are described from their lower left corner unless you further alter the CTM, which is common practice when printing to PostScript from environments where images are drawn top down.

Basically, to solve your problem you need to understand the matrix manipulation and maths described in the PLRM.

Assuming you apply the concat at the point immediately before drawing the image, and no other CTM manipulations have taken place, then the bottom left corner of your image is at 0,0. The concat will not affect that (unless you have a Tx and Ty member in the matrix), but it will alter where the image is drawn. What you need to do is calculate the co-ordinate of the centre of your image when drawn normally, calculate where that co-ordinate is going to end up after the application of the modified CTM, then adjust the shear matrix by adding Tx and Ty values such that the centre co-ordinate will be in the required position. Or translate the origin appropriately.

The key point (probably) is that images have their own Matrix which is applied on top of the CTM; in order to calculate the user space co-ordinate of the centre of the image, you have to apply the image Matrix to the CTM, yourself. And you need to do it again with your shearing matrix applied as well to calculate the position of the centre of the transformed image. Once you have the co-ordinates of the centre of the vanilla image and the centre of the sheared image you know how to translate the current point so that the centre co-ordinate remains invariant.

You haven't supplied an example so I can't work through it for you and I don't have a simple working one to hand. I'll try and come up with one if I get time, and I'll post it here if I do.